# Migrate to Hibernate Annotations from plain hibernate configuration - Also Database needs FK

Tags: java, database, hibernate, database-design

Currently I have following scenario with my project :

- Implemented Hibernate Configuration files (xml) mapping
- Database doesn't have any FK relationship yet

So Now I wanna know that what are the things I need to keep in mind before migrating from hibernate xml configuration to hibernate annotations.

One more thing I wanna specify here is right now with my db i don't have any kind of FK relationship defined....

So obviously I will be applying FK first and then start migrating to annotations...

With this scenario Can anybody have any specific suggestion that I should follow ?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be very careful. Where I work we do everything with annotations so there shouldn't be any specific limitations as far as I can foretell.

It might be wise to migrate a logic chunk of your code at a time if at all possible. But basically it's just painstakingly running through your code and copying everything from the cofnig xml to your entity classes.